# F# Parallel.ForEach invalid method overload

Tags: f#, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

Creating a Parallel.ForEach expression of this form:

```
    let low = max 1 (k-m)
    let high = min (k-1) n
    let rangesize = (high+1-low)/(PROCS*3)

    Parallel.ForEach(Partitioner.Create(low, high+1, rangesize), (fun j ->

            let i = k - j
            if x.[i-1] = y.[j-1] then
                a.[i] <- b.[i-1] + 1
            else 
                a.[i] <- max c.[i] c.[i-1] 
        )) |> ignore
```

Causes me to receive the error: No overloads match for method 'ForEach'. However I am using the `Parallel.ForEach<TSource>` Method (`Partitioner<TSource>, Action<TSource>`) and it seems right to me. Am I missing something?

Edited: I am trying to obtain the same results as the code below (that does not use a Partitioner):

```
let low = max 1 (k-m)
let high = min (k-1) n
let rangesize = (high+1-low)/(PROCS*3)

let A = [| low .. high |]
Parallel.ForEach(A, fun (j:int) ->

    let i = k - j
    if x.[i-1] = y.[j-1] then
        a.[i] <- b.[i-1] + 1
    else 
        a.[i] <- max c.[i] c.[i-1] 
    ) |> ignore
```

Comment: Thanks.. uh.. why was the answer after this one deleted?

Comment: Probably because the author realized it was wrong. ;-]

Comment: Haha :) How do you mean explicitly construct an Action? Declare the function outside instead of using a lambda?

Comment: Can you post the exact error message?  Since we don't have the details of your "action" it's difficult to tell what exactly is wrong without the details of the error.

Comment: error FS0041: No overloads match for method 'ForEach'. The available overloads are shown below (or in the Error List window).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure that you have opened all necessary namespaces, all the values you are using (`low`, `high` and `PROCS`) are defined and that your code does not accidentally redefine some of the names that you're using (like `Partitioner`)?

I created a very simple F# script with this code and it seems to be working fine (I refactored the code to create a partitioner called `p`, but that does not affect the behavior):

```
open System.Threading.Tasks
open System.Collections.Concurrent

let PROCS = 10
let low, high = 0, 100

let p = Partitioner.Create(low, high+1, high+1-low/(PROCS*3))
Parallel.ForEach(p, (fun j ->
    printfn "%A" j  // Print the desired range (using %A as it is a tuple)
)) |> ignore
```

It is important that the value `j` is actually a pair of type `int * int`, so if the body uses it in a wrong way (e.g. as an `int`), you will get the error. In that case, you can add a type annotation to `j` and you would get a more useful error elsewhere:

```
Parallel.ForEach(p, (fun (j:int * int) ->
    printfn "%d" j // Error here, because `j` is used as an int, but it is a pair!
)) |> ignore
```

This means that if you want to perform something for all `j` values in the original range, you need to write something like this:

```
Parallel.ForEach(p, (fun (loJ, hiJ) ->
  for j in loJ .. hiJ - 1 do // Iterate over all js in this partition
    printfn "%d" j           // process the current j
)) |> ignore
```

Aside, I guess that the last argument to `Partitioner.Create` should actually be `(high+1-low)/(PROCS*3)` - you probably want to divide the total number of steps, not just the `low` value.

Comment: I will repaste the rest of my code in the original post for clarity. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Gah, the last argument was definitely wrong. Horribly noob mistake. :( Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I have edited my OP appropriately. What do you mean by 'It is important that the value j is actually a pair of type int * int'?

Comment: Your code assumes that `j` is an `int` (because you are calculating `k - j`) but in fact, it is a pair with the lower and higher boundary for a single iteration. If you add a type annotation (see my second snippet), the overload will be selected correctly, but you will have to modify your code - because the lambda function is called with a _range_ rather than a _single index_.

Comment: I am confused - it appears that j can be cast as an int and work fine with Parallel.ForEach without the use of a Partitioner. But once a Partitioner is used, j is automatically typed as a tuple? How would I iterate through every value of j, then? Extracting the first value of the tuple inside the function body does not work, as expected.

Comment: When you use a partitioner, the lambda gets _ranges_ instead of _single indices_. See my edit that shows how to extract low and high range from the tuple and iterate over them.

Comment: @melange : Why are you using `Partitioner.Create` in this manner if you don't want your function to receive subranges to operate upon? (BTW, [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992635.aspx) are quite clear that this overload of `Partitioner.Create` passes your function a tuple.)

Comment: Thanks, got it. @ildjarn I didn't fully understand Partitioners to begin with, that's why I am experimenting with them.